# Ionic - Device rotation for GPS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, rotation, gps

I am trying to do the following:

I want to make a GPS-like App and that when you rotate (turn) 90º to the left or the right the map rotates to keep having the way "in front of you" just like Google Maps does and the position marker looks up. And also that when you rotate 45º to the right or the left the position marker rotates also 45ª to one direction or another.

I know how to do all the Google Maps stuff. My problem comes about when to detect the rotation. Because I've tried 3 plugins from Ionic: the gyroscope one (that I prefer not to use because many phones has no gyroscope), the device orientation one and the device motion one but I haven't been able to make it work with any of them. The closest I got was with the device orientation plugin which gives you the current degrees of the compass. But the problem now comes that since if you move the device anywhere (for example flip it) its values also changes messing up the result that I want.

I am feeling that I'll need some kind of algebra here which I am very bad at since if I have to use the compass plugin for example, there are many factors to make it work like how inclined is the phone to the user, how tall the user is, etc.

What would be the good approach to do this?

Thanks.